# Is there a complete metric space which has no Cauchy sequence?

Tags: metric-spaces

Definition: A metric space is said to be complete if every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Now, my question is: 
Is there a complete metric space which has no Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Note that eventually constant sequences are Cauchy.

Comment: The countable set of distinct points you mean . Thanks for answering

Comment: As others have pointed out, in any metric space every eventually constant sequence is Cauchy. However, in a discrete metric space these are the only Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constant sequence is Cauchy and convergent.  Any such metric space would have to be a null set.

Comment: Not a null set, just any arbitrary set with the discrete metric.

Comment: No, a null set. If there is a point, make the constant sequence there.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is always a cauchy sequence in any (nonempty) metric space: take $a_n=x$ for some element $x$ of the space. This is trivially Cauchy.

Comment: What about the eventually constant sequences , does it have Cauchy sequences ?

Comment: @HaithamAbuSarries An eventually constant sequence is Cauchy. Just look at the definition. After some point all the differences are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Every constant sequence is a Cauchy sequence.